# java- dynamic JLabel's not showing up

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to create a program that makes the creation of floor layout plans easy for a school project. The user can enter the dimensions of the building which is then portrayed as a grid of labels that can be turned into walls, windows, or doors by clicking on the label. Because walls, windows, and doors have different looks, materials, and such, I created separate classes for each, all which extend a buildingObject. To get it working first I am just focusing on getting buildingObjects on the form.

```
package building.pkg3d.printer;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class buildingObject {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int rotation;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel("wohnvipowa");
    private static final int WIDTH = 10;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 100;

public buildingObject(int x, int y, int rotation, JPanel p) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.rotation = rotation;
    initLabel(p);
}

public void initLabel(JPanel p)
{
    jLabel.setLocation(x, y);
    if (rotation == 1)
        jLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    else
        jLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(HEIGHT, WIDTH));
    jLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    jLabel.setOpaque(true);
    p.add(jLabel);
    p.validate();
    System.out.println("jLabel added to panel");
    System.out.println("jLabel at: " + jLabel.getX() + ", " + jLabel.getY());
    System.out.println("");
    jLabel.setVisible(true);
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public int getRotation() {
    return rotation;
}

public JLabel getjLabel() {
    return jLabel;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "buildingObject{" + "x=" + x + ", y=" + y + ", rotation=" + rotation + ", jLabel=" + jLabel + '}';
}
}
```

I'm quickly testing it on an empty form

```
package building.pkg3d.printer;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class labelTester extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private buildingObject[][] matrix;

/**
 * Creates new form labelTester
 */
public labelTester() {
    initComponents();
    initLayout(1500,1500);
    System.out.println(this.getContentPane().getComponentAt(0, 0).toString());
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 514, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 426, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(labelTester.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(labelTester.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(labelTester.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(labelTester.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new labelTester();
        }
    });
}

private void initLayout(int w, int l)
{
    int numRows = l / 100;
    int numCol = w / 100;

    matrix = new buildingObject[numRows][numCol];
    JPanel p = new JPanel();

    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = new buildingObject(i * 100, j * 100, 1, p);                
        }
    }

    this.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

But whenever I run the program, the labels exist but they don't show up. I need to be able to place the labels at specific x and y values so I don't believe I can use a layout. What can I do to get my labels to show? Or is there a better way to do this that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2):

> I need to be able to place the labels at specific x and y values so I don't believe I can use a layout.

Correct.

However, you code has problems because you don't understand the basics of using layout managers and you are using an IDE to generate your code.

In the `initComponents()` method your IDE is generated the code:

```
javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
```

So this means you are using a `GroupLayout`.

In your `initLayout()` method you are using:

```
this.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

So you are assuming the layout manager is a `BorderLayout`, which it is not. If you want to add the panel to the frame, then you need to use all the constraints required by the `GroupLayout`. Since you don't use the proper constraints the panel is never shown and you will not see the components added to the panel.

Finally, by default JPanel uses a FlowLayout so when you add BuildObjects to the panel they will be located based on the rules of the layout manager.

So what you really need to do is start over. I would suggest NOT using the IDE to generate your GUI code and instead create your GUI manually so you can control the layout manager if required.

Then for the panel that holds the BuildObjects you will need to use a null layout. Then you will be responsible for setting the `size` and `location` of the components you add to the panel.

Now it is generally not a good ideas to use a null layout since Swing was designed to be used with layout managers so the pack() method can determine the preferred size of the panel and scrolling will work properly.

So, to make life easier you can use the [Drag Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/). It allows for random positioning of components but it will implement the other features of a layout manager.